# From eclipse of host machine build and run androidx86(in virtualbox) of second machine

Tags: android, eclipse, virtualbox

I have two computers , second computer is used as second monitor with the help of synergy

iam interested in android programming.

As AVDs are very slow,i use AndroVM as a way to to run my programs from eclipse

my question is i want to click build and run in eclipse of first machine, instead of running in AndroVM on my host machine i want to run it on AndroVM installed on second machine for seamless access with help of synergy.

is there a way to set up in virtual box? iam a noob,detailed explanations would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achiev this via tcp/ip.

1. install X86 Android with this network config

[image]

2. give Android a IP
   Press:
   ALT + F1
   Type:
   netcfg eth0 dhcp
   setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
3. connect adb with the virtual mashine
   **./adb connect [ip from last step]**

Check out my detailed tutorial I wrote a few months ago.
http://standroid.blogspot.de/2012/06/android-4-x86-in-virtualbox.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Something has change in the state of Denmark and now `Alt-F1` doesn't produce the desired result. You can find more details in this SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321715/how-to-figure-out-the-ip-address-of-androvm-4-1-1-r6-1-20130222-emulator