# How to figure out the IP address of AndroVM 4.1.1_r6.1-20130222 emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox

I've installed AndroVM emulator and now want to connect it to `adb` in order to be able to deploy my applications there.

I've [read](http://standroid.blogspot.de/2012/06/android-4-x86-in-virtualbox.html) that in order to do so, it is necessary to press `Alt-F1` on the keyboard and then enter the `netcfg` command.

But when I press `Alt-F1` I see a screen like shown below (no command line).

[image]

*AndroVM configuration* app looks like this:

[image]

How can I find out the IP address of the emulator?

**Update 1 (01.05.2013 20:18 MSK):**

I stopped the VM and tried to configure the network as explained in [this tutorial](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/11223-super-fast-alternative-emulator-x86-android.html). `Adapter 1` must be set to `host only`, but when I try to select this option, I get the error message `On the "Network: Adapter 1" you did not select the host-only adapter`.

[image]

Comment: Hey Dude, Is the second image you just edited the "androVm Configuration" is talked about in this post? (http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/11223-super-fast-alternative-emulator-x86-android.html) 7. From the Android VM launch the AndroVM Configuration app to find out the IP settings. But i can't see any IP in your screen,strange.

Comment: @SimonSchubert It seems to be a problem with the configuration (see update 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by configuring the host-only adapter (`File -> Preferences -> Network`).

Answer (score 1):

> about phone->status, you will see ip address. Or install a terminal app.

Several users have the same ALT+F1 problem.

That you don't see your IP in the androVm Configuration app still confuses me, maybe your mashine itself has some wrong network settings?

Comment: Ad `Phone->Status`: How can I do this? I opened the Phone app, but I don't know where the status part is.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko: It's `Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> IP Address`.

Answer (score 1):

(just want to add another answer because I found your post while Googling)

AFAIK, Alt+F1 is available with Android x86, and this distribution is NOT the same as AndroVM!
In AndroVM, one possibility to find your IP is to install a terminal (Terminal Emulator for instance) and to type "ip addr show" (or "netcfg").

This is working in my VM, I see all my interfaces with my addresses.